# Python, write tuple into binary file

Tags: python, tuples, binaryfiles

I'm trying to write tuple `('hola', 'cheese', '1235265')`, `('hey', 'weird', '30193')` getting from mysql DB, putting values into binary file

I saw it got DB table as tuple. Tried to convert into binary, didn't work well.
So i tried another with tuple -> string -> binary, still has an error...
is there any good ways to write tuple to binary file in Python?

```
for i in text_query:
    query = "select * from " + i
    curs.execute(query)
    # Data Fetch from Mysql

    rows = curs.fetchall()
    results = [".".join(map(str, r)) for r in rows]
    make_file(name,i,results)
conn.close()

def make_file(name, filename, rows):
if filename == 'student':
    with open(name + '_' + filename + '.dat', 'wb') as fp:
        for i in rows:
            fp.write(bytearray(rows + '\n'))

elif filename == 'course':
    with open(name + '_' + filename + '.dat', 'wb') as fp:
        for i in rows:
            fp.write(bytearray(rows + '\n'))

elif filename == 'course_taken':
    with open(name + '_' + filename + '.dat', 'wb') as fp:
        for i in rows:
            fp.write(bytearray(rows + '\n'))

else:
    return 0;
```

Comment: Why don't you use `pickle`?

Comment: I'd like to.. this is some of my homework on college :(

Comment: You either have to come up with some format for this to make any sense or you know something about the format and structure of this data you're not including in the question.

Comment: Is this code properly formatted? Seems like you'd just get a syntax error.

Comment: You need to [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your data.  If you can't use an existing solution, you're going to have to write your own.

Comment: You mentioned this is homework, does it have to be written to file in binary format?  Even if you cant use another module to do the serialisation for you, writing to the file as as some form of text will be simple, and standard python can do a lot of the hard work for you, and the resulting file will be easy to check/re-use.

Comment: Yeah i actually tried several file read/write in python before. This homework should be binary format... Maybe i'll try other language such as C++ (Need to get DB from Mysql and make it into binary file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a binary representation of your data to file easily enough, not that it would be a good idea, from an encoding point of view. Nor will it be easy to read back in, but this will work:

```
def make_text_file(name, filename, rows):
if filename == 'student':   # 
    with open(name + '_' + filename + '.txt', 'w') as fp:
        row_index = 0
        fp.write('<record start>')
        for i in rows:
            row_index += 1
            fp.write('<row {0}>{1}</row>'.format(row_index, i))
        fp.write('<record end>\n')


def make_binary_file(name, filename, rows):
    if filename == 'student': 
        with open(name + '_' + filename + '.dat', 'wb') as fp:
            row_index = 0
            for i in rows:
                row_index += 1
                fp.write(bytes((i), 'utf8'))

def test_things():
    """ Generate some data to write to file """

    rows = ('hola', 'cheese', '1235265')
    #make_file('student', 'test_student.txt', rows)
    make_text_file('test', 'student', rows)

    rows = ('hey', 'weird', '30193')
    make_binary_file('test', 'student', rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_things()
```